# No veo productos comprados php mvc

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy en mi módulo de compras y ya se pueden realizar. Uso dos tablas; una llamada compras y la otra detallesCompras
Cuando realizas la compra se debe seleccionar el proveedor, se seleccionan los productos y se van agregando filas para seleccionar la cantidad de dicho producto y costo y un total se actualiza. Después tengo un botón llamado editar que al dar clic me tiene que traer la modal con esos datos. Ya tengo mi js, mi ajax, controlador y modelos y ya tanto en consola como en la pestaña network me trae los valores de ambas tablas pero no puedo hacer para visualizar lo comprado.

```
    introducir el código aquí
  <!--================
    AGREGAR COMPRA
    ================ -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modalAgregar">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Realizar Compra</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label>Proveedor: <code>*</code></label>
                              <select class="form-control-boder select2 select2-danger"
                                  data-dropdown-css-class="select2-danger" name="nuevoProveedor" id="agregarProveedor">
                                  <option selected>Seleccionar Proveedor</option>
                                  <?php
                                    $item = null;
                                    $valor = null;
                                    $proveedores = ControladorProveedores::ctrMostrarProveedores($item, $valor);
                                    foreach ($proveedores as $key => $value) {
                                        echo '<option value="'.$value["id"].'">'.$value["nombre"].'</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                              </select>
                              <p id="errorAgregarProveedor" style="color:white;"></p>
                              <span id="editarProveedorHelp" class="form-text text-danger" style="display:none;">Debes
                                  seleccionar un Proveedor.</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label>Productos: <code>*</code></label>
                              <select class="form-control-boder select2 select2-danger"
                                  data-dropdown-css-class="select2-danger" name="nuevoProducto">
                                  <option selected>Seleccionar Producto</option>
                                  <?php
    $item = null;
    $valor = null;
    $productos = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarProductos($item, $valor, 'Si');

    foreach ($productos as $key => $value) {
        echo '<option value="'.$value["id"].'" data-costo="'.$value["costo"].'" data-precio="'.$value["precio"].'">'.$value["nombre"].'</option>';
    }
?>

                              </select>
                              <span id="editarProductoHelp" class="form-text text-danger" style="display:none;">Debes
                                  seleccionar un Producto.</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- Aquí es donde se agregarán las filas de productos -->
                      <div id="filasProductos"></div>

                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4"></div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                              <label style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold; color: white;">Total
                                  General<code></code></label>
                              <input type="hidden" class="form-control totalGeneral" name="totalGeneral" min="0"
                                  value="0">
                              <p class="totalGeneralDisplay" style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold; color: white;">
                              </p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4"></div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Notas Adicionales: <code></code></label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-border" name="nuevaNota"
                              pattern="^[0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$" title="Solo se aceptan letras, números y espacios."
                              maxlength="150">
                      </div>




                      <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                      </div>
                      <?php
                    $crearCompra = new ControladorCompras();
                    $crearCompra -> ctrCrearCompra();
                      ?>

                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div>

  <!--================
    EDITAR COMPRA
    ================ -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modalEditar">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Editar Compra</h4>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label>Proveedor: <code>*</code></label>
                              <select class="form-control-boder select2 select2-danger"
                                  data-dropdown-css-class="select2-danger" name="editarProveedor" id="editarProveedor">
                                  <option selected>Seleccionar Proveedor</option>
                                  <?php
                                    $item = null;
                                    $valor = null;
                                    $proveedores = ControladorProveedores::ctrMostrarProveedores($item, $valor);
                                    foreach ($proveedores as $key => $value) {
                                        echo '<option value="'.$value["id"].'">'.$value["nombre"].'</option>';
                                    }
                                    ?>
                              </select>
                              <p id="errorAgregarProveedor" style="color:white;"></p>
                              <span id="editarProveedorHelp" class="form-text text-danger" style="display:none;">Debes
                                  seleccionar un Proveedor.</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                              <label>Productos: <code>*</code></label>
                              <select class="form-control-boder select2 select2-danger"
                                  data-dropdown-css-class="select2-danger" name="editarProducto" id="editarProducto">
                                  <option selected>Seleccionar Producto</option>
                                  <?php
    $item = null;
    $valor = null;
    $productos = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarProductos($item, $valor, 'Si');

    foreach ($productos as $key => $value) {
        echo '<option value="'.$value["id"].'" data-costo="'.$value["costo"].'" data-precio="'.$value["precio"].'">'.$value["nombre"].'</option>';
    }
?>

                              </select>
                              <span id="editarProductoHelp" class="form-text text-danger" style="display:none;">Debes
                                  seleccionar un Producto.</span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- Aquí es donde se agregarán las filas de productos -->
                      <div id="filasProductos"></div>

                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4"></div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                              <label style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold; color: white;">Total
                                  General<code></code></label>
                              <input type="hidden" class="form-control totalGeneral" name="totalGeneral" min="0"
                                  value="0">
                              <p class="totalGeneralDisplay" style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold; color: white;">
                              </p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4"></div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label>Notas Adicionales: <code></code></label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-border" name="editarNota" id="editarNota"
                              pattern="^[0-9a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$" title="Solo se aceptan letras, números y espacios."
                              maxlength="150">
                      </div>




                      <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                      </div>

                  </form>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div>

    introducir el código aquí
/*=====================
EDITAR COMPRAS
 =====================*/
 $(".btnEditarCompras").click(function(){

    var idCompras = $(this).attr("idCompras");
    var idDetallesCompras = $(this).attr("idDetallesCompras");

    var datos= new FormData();
    datos.append("idCompras",idCompras);
    datos.append("idDetallesCompras",idDetallesCompras);

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/crear-compra.ajax.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(respuesta){
            console.log("respuesta", respuesta);

            // Establecer el valor del campo con ID "idCompras" al ID de la compra
            $("#idCompras").val(respuesta["compra"]["id"]);
            $("#editarProveedor").val(respuesta["proveedor_id"]).trigger('change.select2');
            $("#editarNota").val(respuesta["notas"]);

            
            // Crear una cadena de HTML para los detalles de la compra
            var detallesHTML = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < respuesta["detalles"].length; i++) {
              var detalleCompra = respuesta["detalles"][i];
              // Agregar una fila a la cadena de HTML para cada detalle de la compra
              detallesHTML += '<tr>';
              detallesHTML += '<td>' + detalleCompra["producto"] + '</td>';
              detallesHTML += '<td>' + detalleCompra["cantidad"] + '</td>';
              detallesHTML += '<td>' + detalleCompra["costo"] + '</td>';
              detallesHTML += '<td>' + detalleCompra["precio"] + '</td>';
              detallesHTML += '<td>' + detalleCompra["total"] + '</td>';
              detallesHTML += '</tr>';
            }
            
            // Establecer el HTML del elemento con ID "tablaDetalles" a la cadena de HTML creada
            $("#tablaDetalles").html(detallesHTML);
            
        }
    })
})


/*======================
AÑADIR FILAS DE PRODUCTO 
=====================*/
$(document).on('change', '.cantidadProducto, .costoProducto', function() {
    var cantidad = $(this).closest('.row').find('.cantidadProducto').val();
    var costo = $(this).closest('.row').find('.costoProducto').val();
    var total = cantidad * costo;
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.totalProducto').val(total);
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select[name="nuevoProducto"]').change(function(){
        var productId = $(this).val();
        var productName = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        var costo = $(this).find('option:selected').data('costo');
        var precio = $(this).find('option:selected').data('precio');
        
        console.log("Costo: " + costo); // Imprime el costo en la consola
        console.log("Precio: " + precio); // Imprime el precio en la consola

        var newRow = `
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Artículo: <code>*</code></label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-border" value="${productName}" readonly>
                        <input type="hidden" name="nuevoProducto[]" value="${productId}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label>Cantidad: <code>*</code></label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control cantidadProducto" name="cantidadProducto[]" min="1">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label>Costo Unitario: <code>*</code></label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control costoProducto" name="costoProducto[]" min="0" value="${costo}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label>Precio Unitario: <code>*</code></label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control precioProducto" name="precioProducto[]" min="0" value="${precio}">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                    <label>Total: <code>*</code></label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control totalProducto" name="totalProducto[]" min="0" value="0" readonly>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger eliminarFila">Eliminar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        `;
        $('#filasProductos').append(newRow);
    });
});

/*======================
BORRAR FILAS DE PRODUCTO 
=====================*/
$(document).on('click', '.eliminarFila', function(){
    console.log("Fila eliminada");
    $(this).closest('.row').remove();
    updateTotalGeneral();
});


/*===============
ACTUALIZAR TOTAL 
===============*/

$(document).on('input', '.cantidadProducto, .costoProducto', function(){
    console.log("Actualizando total");
    var row = $(this).closest('.row');
    var quantity = parseFloat(row.find('.cantidadProducto').val());
    var cost = parseFloat(row.find('.costoProducto').val());
    if (!isNaN(quantity) && !isNaN(cost)) {
        row.find('.totalProducto').val(quantity * cost);
    } else {
        row.find('.totalProducto').val(0);
    }
});

/*===============
TOTAL GENERAL 
===============*/
function updateTotalGeneral() {
    console.log("Actualizando total general");
    var totalGeneral = 0;
    $('.totalProducto').each(function() {
        var totalProducto = $(this).val();
        var totalProductoNumber = parseFloat(totalProducto.replace(/,/g, ''));
        totalGeneral += totalProductoNumber;
    });
    $('.totalGeneral').val(totalGeneral);
    $('.totalGeneralDisplay').text(totalGeneral.toLocaleString('en-US', { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }));
}

$(document).on('input', '.cantidadProducto, .costoProducto', function() {
    // Actualizar el total para esta fila
    console.log("Actualizando total de fila");
    var quantity = $(this).closest('.row').find('.cantidadProducto').val();
    var cost = $(this).closest('.row').find('.costoProducto').val();
    var total = quantity * cost;
    $(this).closest('.row').find('.totalProducto').val(total);

    // Actualizar el total general
    updateTotalGeneral();
});


/*============================
MOSTRAR COSTOS Y PRECIOS
==============================*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="nuevoProducto"]').change(function() {
        console.log("Mostrando costos y precios");
        var costo = $(this).find('option:selected').data('costo');
        var precio = $(this).find('option:selected').data('precio');

        // Encuentra la fila más cercana
        var row = $(this).closest('.row');

        // Encuentra los campos de costo y precio dentro de esa fila y establece sus valores
        row.find('input[name="costoProducto"]').val(costo);
        row.find('input[name="precioProducto"]').val(precio);
    });
});

$(document).on('change', 'input[name="costoProducto"], input[name="precioProducto"]', function() {
    console.log("Enviando solicitud AJAX");
    var row = $(this).closest('.row');
    var productId = row.find('input[name="nuevoProducto[]"]').val();
    var newCost = row.find('input[name="costoProducto"]').val();
    var newPrice = row.find('input[name="precioProducto"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/crear-compra.ajax.php",
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'updateProduct',
            id: productId,
            costo: newCost,
            precio: newPrice
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("Respuesta de la solicitud AJAX: ", response);
            // Aquí puedes manejar la respuesta de tu script PHP
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Error en la solicitud AJAX: ", textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: ***pero no puedo hacer para visualizar lo comprado.*** no puedes visualizarlo hasta que haya pasado por el checkout de la compra y pagado con uno de los metodos de pago habilitados... incluso para ver los comprado en teoria deberia de ir a un reporte de ***Historial de Compras***